# 'Object.observe' is deprecated. Polymer.js

Tags: cordova, polymer

I'm using cordova + Polymer 0.5 (yes, I know it's deprecated) and getting the warning:
"'Object.observe' is deprecated and will be removed in M50, around April 2016." in polymer.js

How does it affects on existing on Polymer apps?
Will apps that use Polymer 0.5 be working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As most of the browsers never had `Object.observe` in the first place, Polymer 0.5 used a polyfill ([observe-js](https://github.com/Polymer/observe-js)) where it was not available. So once `Object.observed` is removed, it should just fall back to the polyfill and still work. However, performance may suffer.

I have just tested this with a Polymer 0.5 application that I still have around and Chrome Beta (Version 50.0.2661.26). In this version, `Object.observe` has been removed and my application still works fine.